# How to obtain mingw-w64 version 9.3.0 or older for MSYS2?

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

I need gcc version 9.3.0 or an older version (> 5.0) of mingw-w64, either i686 or x86_64 for MSYS2. Where can I find this package?

Comment: Could you be specific about what package you are trying to downgrade by providing the full name of the package according to pacman (for example, `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`)?  Or if you're not sure, just say a few of the files you're trying to downgrade or what goals you are trying to achieve; we can figure out the package name from that.  Also note that the [mingw-w64 project](https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/tags) is currently on version 6.0.1, so are you actually talking about GCC or some other component?